# 2018.2.7 Unity Space Shooter tutorial has obsoleted problems which Text and SceneManager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm newbie of 2018.2.7f1(64bit) Unity.

Space Shooter the official Unity tutorials have obsoleted problems.

● GUIText obsoleted. Now have to use Text.

● Application.LoadLevel and LoadedLevel obsoleted. Now have to use SceneManager.

I'm getting stuck here.

The ScoreText is working. It worked at Game Play mode. But RestartText and GameOverText doesn't working. When Player character dead, The hazard Enemy waves just keep going and Texts doesn't shown up.

How can I solve these problems? Would you guys let me know where should I fix?I'd read documentary of Text and SceneManager and still don't get it. No error have shown in Console.

etc. I'm making a similar shooting game but base is same with Space Shooter. It's not big deal just I noticed.

●GameController Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject EnemySummon;
    public Vector2 spawnValues;
    public int EnemySummonCount;
    public float SpawnWait;
    public float startWait;
    public float waveWait;

    public Text scoreText;
    public Text restartText;
    public Text gameOverText;

    private bool gameOver;
    private bool restart;
    private int score;


void Start()
    {
        gameOver = false;
        restart = false;
        restartText.text = null;
        gameOverText.text = null;
        score = 0;
        UpdateScore();
        StartCoroutine (SpawnWaves());
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (restart)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.R))
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Play", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnWaves ()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWait);
            for (int i = 0; i < EnemySummonCount; i++)
            {
                Vector2 spawnPosition = new Vector2(spawnValues.x, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-spawnValues.y, spawnValues.y));
                Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
                Instantiate(EnemySummon, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(SpawnWait);

                if (gameOver)
                {
                    restartText.text = "Press 'R' for Restart";
                    restart = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);
        }
    }

    public void AddScore (int newScoreValue)
    {
        score += newScoreValue;
        UpdateScore();
    }

    void UpdateScore ()
    {
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }

    public void GameOver ()
    {
        gameOverText.text = "Game Over!";
        gameOver = true;
    }
}
```

●DestroyByContact Code

`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyByContatct_Summon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int scoreValue;
    private GameController gameController;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject gameControllerObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameController");
        if (gameControllerObject != null)
        {
            gameController = gameControllerObject.GetComponent<GameController>();
        }
        if (gameController == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Cannot find 'GameController' script");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            return;
        }
        if (other.tag == "EnemySummon")
        {
            return;
        }
        if (other.tag == "BackGround")
        {
            return;
        }
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            gameController.GameOver ();
        }
        gameController.AddScore(scoreValue);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Put the gameOver condition into wave loop is weird. And the startWait only need execute one time.

```
IEnumerator SpawnWaves ()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWait);
    while (true)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < EnemySummonCount; i++)
        {
            Vector2 spawnPosition = new Vector2(spawnValues.x, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-spawnValues.y, spawnValues.y));
            Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            Instantiate(EnemySummon, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(SpawnWait);


        }
        if (gameOver)
        {
                restartText.text = "Press 'R' for Restart";
                restart = true;
                break;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);
    }
}
```